# PHP Regular Expression - Detect if string contains a word but not within another

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a system written in PHP which aggregates records from a number of databases in to one. When doing this I need to detect if each record is `ABNORMAL` and if it is, flag it as being so.

To do this I need a pattern for `preg_match()` so it will return false if the given string contains the word `NORMAL` but not `ABNORMAL`. The string given may be over multiple lines.

The problem I am having is that the word `ABNORMAL` *contains* the word `NORMAL`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not first search for `ABNORMAL` and then for `NORMAL` if the first search returns `false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the word boundry character `\b`:

```
preg_match("|\bNORMAL\b|", $subject);
```

Note that it is case sensitive, the case insensitive version is this:

```
preg_match("|\bNORMAL\b|i", $subject);
```

---

Though if you have control over you database, you might want to use 0 and 1 (or at least N and A) instead of NORMAL and ABNORMAL.